# How give padding for path?

Tags: android

Hi in the below code want to reduce the height to half from the below path .Second pathdata want to make it half

can any one help me how to reduce.Between these two gap want more

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:viewportWidth="500"
    android:viewportHeight="749"
    android:width="625dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:height="936.25dp">



    <group android:scaleX="0.1"
        android:scaleY="-0.1"
        android:translateY="749">

        <path
            android:pathData="M439 7416C282 7361 169 7248 113 7090l-23 -65 0 -1751c0 -1693 1 -1753 19 -1806 35 -101 99 -185 184 -241 57 -38 90 -50 442 -162 132 -42 701 -224 1265 -405 564 -180 1084 -346 1155 -368 72 -22 362 -114 645 -206 558 -179 630 -196 749 -177 165 27 267 129 316 316 13 53 15 321 15 2410 0 2572 4 2397 -58 2523 -56 115 -184 223 -310 262 -63 20 -97 20 -2036 20l-1971 0 -66 -24z"
            android:fillColor="@color/back_blue" />
        <path
            android:pathData="M498 2820C322 2790 207 2702 128 2534L95 2465 92 1476C90 496 90 486 110 424 155 289 255 178 389 112l76 -37 1998 -3 1997 -2 63 21c160 53 293 193 338 357 17 59 19 106 19 407 0 369 -4 404 -56 507 -55 109 -179 205 -304 237 -25 7 -54 16 -65 21 -11 5 -206 68 -433 140 -227 72 -677 214 -1000 316 -323 102 -623 197 -667 211 -44 14 -343 108 -665 210 -322 102 -691 218 -820 259 -240 76 -271 81 -372 64z"
            android:fillColor="@color/White" />


    </group>


</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:width="625dp"
    android:height="936.25dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:viewportWidth="500"
    android:viewportHeight="749">

    <group
        android:pivotX="50"
        android:pivotY="15"
        android:scaleX="0.85"
        android:scaleY="0.9">

        <group
            android:scaleX="0.1"
            android:scaleY="-0.1"
            android:translateY="749">

            <path
                android:fillColor="@color/black"
                android:pathData="M439 7416C282 7361 169 7248 113 7090l-23 -65 0 -1751c0 -1693 1 -1753 19 -1806 35 -101 99 -185 184 -241 57 -38 90 -50 442 -162 132 -42 701 -224 1265 -405 564 -180 1084 -346 1155 -368 72 -22 362 -114 645 -206 558 -179 630 -196 749 -177 165 27 267 129 316 316 13 53 15 321 15 2410 0 2572 4 2397 -58 2523 -56 115 -184 223 -310 262 -63 20 -97 20 -2036 20l-1971 0 -66 -24z" />
            <path
                android:fillColor="@color/white"
                android:pathData="M498 2820C322 2790 207 2702 128 2534L95 2465 92 1476C90 496 90 486 110 424 155 289 255 178 389 112l76 -37 1998 -3 1997 -2 63 21c160 53 293 193 338 357 17 59 19 106 19 407 0 369 -4 404 -56 507 -55 109 -179 205 -304 237 -25 7 -54 16 -65 21 -11 5 -206 68 -433 140 -227 72 -677 214 -1000 316 -323 102 -623 197 -667 211 -44 14 -343 108 -665 210 -322 102 -691 218 -820 259 -240 76 -271 81 -372 64z" />


        </group>

    </group>
</vector>
```